# How to Improve the Performance of mongodb long running Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am new to mongoDb, i am trying to update the fields for Each Records for around 10 to 15k records. When i am trying to update the records the query blocks whole database, the Running query will allow me to do any read or write operations till the Query Execution completes, is there anyway to improve the performance for this kind of Queries.

Here is My Code:

```
var ExisitingData=[{"isActive" : true, 
    "barcode" : "8908001921015",     
    "mrp" : 2000, 
},
{"isActive" : true, 
    "barcode" : "7808001921019",     
    "mrp" : 1000, 
}
....15k]
var updatedRsult=[];
    async.forEach(ExisistingData, function (item, innerCallback) {
        exports.populateData(item, function (err, populatedResult) {
            if (err) {
                innerCallback(err);
            }
            if(populatedResult==true)
                totalRecordsUpdated++;
            else
                totalIgnoredRecords++;
            innerCallback();

        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("FinalDone");
        var h1={}
        h1['totalRecordsUpdated'] = totalRecordsUpdated;
        h1['totalIgnoredRecords'] = totalIgnoredRecords;
        updatedResult.push(h1);
        updateCheck(null, updatedResult);
    });




exports.populateData=function(item, mainCallback) {
    var updated = false;
    async.parallel([
        function (callback1) {
            Test.update({
                $and: [
                    {'barcode': item['barcode']},
                    {'mrp': {$lt: parseInt(item['mrp'])}}
                ]
            }, {$set: {'mrp': parseInt(item['mrp'])}}, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback1();
                }

                else {
                    if (result['nModified'] == 1) {
                        console.log("Its Updated");
                        console.log(item);

                       updated=true;
                        callback1()
                    }
                    else {
                        callback1()
                    }
                }

            });
        }

    ], function done(err) {
        mainCallback(null,updated);
    });
};
```

Comment: try  `async.eachLimit(ExisistingData, 10, function (item, innerCallback) { `

Comment: Don't load all the data into an array but process streams instead. Run bulk operations to reduce the write and response overhead.

Comment: @NeilLunn Hi can you  please give one Example on that.

Comment: I have no idea in the context of your question where the `ExistingData` which you just mark as being an array 15k long is coming from. The first part of the process would need to start with reading that data from whatever source you are getting it in an efficient way and then passing it on for the update operations. So you might start by explaining the source of the data. Web API? CSV? etc.

Comment: @NeilLunn the data source is coming from the CSV